# Error accessing live photo from app extension

Tags: ios9, photo, live, phlivephoto

So, I am currently building an app extension that supports working with live photos. However, when attempting to extract a live photo from NSItemProvider, the completion handler called from this method:

```
[itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeLivePhoto options:nil completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

The completion handler will throw an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)"

Here is a more complete code snippet:

```
NSExtensionItem *item = self.extensionContext.inputItems.firstObject;
for (NSItemProvider* itemProvider in item.attachments) {
    if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeLivePhoto]) {
       for (NSString* typeIdentifier in itemProvider.registeredTypeIdentifiers) {
            [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:typeIdentifier options:nil completionHandler:completionHandler];
       }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: You're not the only one. Seems like maybe NSItemProviders aren't compatible with live photos.

Comment: Did you manage to get the live photo from the `NSItemProvider`?

Comment: I'm wondering if this has something to do with sharing extensions specifically. I can get a live photo in my main app (from NSItemProvider), but not from within my sharing extension.